# Integrating OAuth with Kuzzle

Tags: node.js, oauth, passport.js, backend, kuzzle

I want use an OAuth provider to authenticate requests to my kuzzle instance.

What is the standard or preferred way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kuzzle support multiple authentication strategies for the same user. It mean that the same user can login with username/password or 0Aut or Ldap, etc.

Kuzzle use [Passeport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/), so every strategy supported by Passeport.js can be integrated. To do this, you will have to develop an [authentication plugin](https://docs.kuzzle.io/plugins/1/essentials/strategies/).

Concerning 0Auth, we already provide an authentication plugin, check it out: https://github.com/kuzzleio/kuzzle-plugin-auth-passport-oauth

*Full disclosure: I work at Kuzzle as core developer*